# ASP Core Angular SPA Template module.ts configuration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

There are 3 different app.module files in ASP Core SPA Template

1. app.module.client.ts
2. app.module.server.ts
3. app.module.shared.ts

I've included my services in app.module.shared.ts providers but it still shows no provider defined at runtime. Usually we have a single app.module.ts file in angular and when I define my services there it was working just fine. Any help would be highly appreciated.

app.module.share.ts

```
export const sharedConfig: NgModule = {
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    NavComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    PluginComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    DashboardUIComponent,
    SchoolInfoComponent,
    HomeMainComponent,
    StudentInfoComponent,
    NavMainComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    ClassInfoComponent,
    ClassComponent
],
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES),
],
providers: [MenuService, VariablesService, navPillsService] };
```

app.module.client.ts

```
@NgModule({
bootstrap: sharedConfig.bootstrap,
declarations: sharedConfig.declarations,
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ...sharedConfig.imports
],
providers: [
    { provide: 'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: location.origin, ...sharedConfig.providers }
] }) export class AppModule { }
```

app.module.server.ts

```
@NgModule({
bootstrap: sharedConfig.bootstrap,
declarations: sharedConfig.declarations,
imports: [
    ServerModule,
    ...sharedConfig.imports
],
providers: sharedConfig.providers  }) export class AppModule { }
```

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code may not be correct:

```
providers: [
    { provide: 'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: location.origin, ...sharedConfig.providers }
] }) export class AppModule { }
```

I think the sharedConfig piece has to be outside of the braces?

```
providers: [
    { provide: 'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: location.origin}, 
     ...sharedConfig.providers
] }) export class AppModule { }
```